# How to convert a date from Model.FirstOrDefault() to short date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to format a date to the short date format. The date is retrieved using @Model.FirstOrDefault() in my view. How can I reformat this to the short format?
I'd also like to be able to ad one day to the date later on in the View.

I have tried using .Value.ToShortDateString, but this gives me the following error: "Cannot convert method group 'ToShortDateString' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

I've tried

```
@Model.FirstOrDefault().kurser.startdato.Value.ToShortDateString;
```

Which gives me the error. When I just use:

```
@Model.FirstOrDefault().kurser.startdato
```

I get the following result: 07-01-2019 00:00:00. What I want is 07-01-2019. Is this even possible, or do I need a completely differentapproach?

Comment: `.ToShortDateString()` is a method.  You need parentheses for proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.7.2).
Just go to your model class and add before the date property these annotations

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime startdato {get;set;}
```

Also you need to add the relevant using directive

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

and eventually add the required reference

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, as it lets me add days to @Model.FirstOrDefault() further into my view. But I'm giving everyone a point for being useful - thanks all!

Comment: Check about DataAnnotations. They give you a lot. Formatting, display custom titles for your fields, and basic Validation (date and numbers input, max/min length over strings, comparison between fields), translation using resources. And just putting a declarative attribute to your field.

Answer (score 2):

if the startdato is `DateTime`
you can format the `DateTime` `toString(" ");`
like this :`@Model.FirstOrDefault().kurser.startdato.ToString("hh:mm tt",null);`
this example will give you the hours and minutes of your DateTime
if that's what you meant.
here is a link to get the idea of formating types [String format datetime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings
This is a better link sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

```
var shortDate = yourVariable.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

This takes your date and formats it with .ToString()

Answer (score 1):

[`ToShortDateString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a method. Therefore it needs to be invoked by adding parentheses:

```
@Model.FirstOrDefault().kurser.startdato.Value.ToShortDateString()
```